# PHP Run Function and echo Result

Tags: php, function

I need to check a name (from $_GET) several times against a current passed name.
The function called is checkName and the $_GET is $CurrentName, the passed name to check if equal is $ActiveName. I need to echo the result for font color and passed name. See code below.

Error I get:
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in Filename.php:33 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in Filename.php on line 33

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>JW.APK</title>
<style>
@font-face {font-family: 'SourceSansProRegular'; src: url('font/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
@font-face {font-family: 'SourceSansProBlack'; src: url('font/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf') format('truetype'); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }
body {color:#151515; font-family: SourceSansProRegular; padding: 5px; }
textarea {width: 100%; }
th {position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; }
td {font-size: 0.75em; }
table {margin-top: 10px; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
font {font-weight: bold; }
p {font-size: 0.7em; text-align: justify; }
</style>
</head><body>     
<?php
$CurrentName = $_GET["name"];
echo $CurrentName;

function checkName($ActiveName)
{
    if ($CurrentName == $ActiveName)
    {
        echo "<font color='#235689'><b>$ActiveName</b></font>";
    } else {
        echo "<font color='#000000'><b>$ActiveName</b></font>";
    }
}
?>
<table border='0' width='100%'>
 <tr>
  <td width='40%' bgcolor='#AED7FF' height='30' >Name 1</td>
  <td width='60%' bgcolor='#AED7FF' height='30' ><?php $checkName("Robert"); ?></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td width='40%' bgcolor='#AED7FF' height='30' >Name 2</b></td>
  <td width='60%' bgcolor='#AED7FF' height='30' ><?php $checkName("Jackson"); ?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to call the function many times.

Comment: `$CurrentName` is not available inside your function and it is named `checkName()`, not `$checkName()`. (fyi, `<font>` is deprecated)

Comment: Okay I changed the code function to: 
```<?php
$CurrentName = $_GET["name"];
echo $CurrentName;

function checkName($ActiveName,$CurrentName)
{
    if ($CurrentName == $ActiveName)
    {
        echo "<font color='#235689'><b>$ActiveName</b></font>";
    } else {
        echo "<font color='#000000'><b>$ActiveName</b></font>";
 }
}
?>```

and get the same error

Comment: And did you also change the call to your function from `$checkName()` to `checkName()`, which is the reason for the error?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare that `$CurrentName`, you can pass that `$CurrentName` as a argument in `checkName` function and use it inside the `checkName` function. Now Call the function without `$` eg. `checkName($ActiveName, $CurrentName);`

```
$CurrentName = $_GET["name"];

function checkName($ActiveName, $CurrentName) {
    if ($CurrentName == $ActiveName) {
        echo "<font color='#235689'><b>$ActiveName</b></font>";
    } else {
        echo "<font color='#000000'><b>$ActiveName</b></font>";
    } 
 }

$ActiveName = "Monkey D Luffy"
checkName($ActiveName, $CurrentName)
```

Hope this helpful,

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function in a wrong way in the table.
the correct way of calling the function is **checkName("Robert")** without the $.

Comment: fyi, we usually vote to close/flag questions caused by a typo - they're generally of no use to any other user